# What is the normalization of $k[z][t]/(t^p+t^{p-1}z-z)$? ($k$ is characteristic $p$)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$.

What is the normalization of $k[z][t]/(t^p+t^{p-1}z-z)$?

The normalization of the Spec of this ring describes the restriction of the standard Artin-Schreier cover of $\mathbb{P}^1_k$, to the complement of $0$ (here $t$ is a uniformizer at $\infty$). Thus, since the Artin-Schreier cover is genus 0, the normalization should be isomorphic to $k[T]$. Since this ring doesn't seem to be isomorphic to $k[T]$, I don't think it's normal.

Hence, what is its normalization? (And what is the isomorphism from $k[T]$ to its normalization?)

Comment: DId you try to find the normalization? The proof of the normalization theorem say in Bourbaki gives you an algorithm to proceed, and you need only normalize one polynomial here.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I tried a few things, which did not work. Can you give a more precise reference for the algorithm you referred to?

Comment: If $f=t^p+t^{p-1}z-z$, then $f_t=(p-1)t^{p-2}z$ and $f_z=t^{p-1}-1$. So, a point where all of $f,f_t,f_z$ vanish would mean $z=0$, since $t\neq 0$, being a root of 1, But, then $t=0$, since $f=0$. So, Jacobian condition would force the ring to be normal. Have I made a mistake?